# If a value matches in columns in any two rows, I want to highlight only the value in the row that comes second in Excel using VBA. How?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a calendar in Excel using VBA. It looks as shown:
[image]

Column B is the month column. The month starts on column B on the week (row) in which the first day of the month occurs. Example, February starts in row 6 although there are some last days of January in the same row.

I want to highlight the holidays. For example, I have holidays on January 1, which is highlighted in cyan color. I have written a code by defining an two-dimensional array object `my_holidays(x,y)`. x refers to the month and y refers to the day based on following:
[image]

I wrote a code which searches for month in column B and the day on columns C to I, and highlights if it finds the match:

```
Dim last_row As Integer
last_row = ws1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).row

Dim row As Integer
Dim column As Integer

For row = 1 To last_row
    For column = 3 To 9
        For i = 1 To num_holidays
            
            If ws1.Range("B" & row).Value = my_holidays(i, 1) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = my_holidays(i, 2) Then
                ws1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbCyan
            End If
            
            
        Next i
        
        
    Next column
    
Next row
```

My problem is that if I have holiday on days such as March 29, it highlights two rows here 10 and 14 as shown in the screenshot above. However, the 29 day in row 10 corresponds to February.

How can I modify my code such that if the holiday corresponds to two rows for a month, it should select the second row using VBA in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Introduce the `bFirstRow` variable to distinguish the first row of each month.
- Fix the logic to mark 27 Feb.
- Loop through data from the 2nd row `For row = 2`, otherwise `Cells(row - 1, 2)` raises error.

```vb
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim bFirstRow As Boolean
    Dim sMth As String
    For row = 2 To last_row
        If ws1.Cells(row, 2) <> ws1.Cells(row - 1, 2) Then
            bFirstRow = True
        Else
            bFirstRow = False
        End If
        For column = 3 To 9
            If bFirstRow And ws1.Cells(row, column) > 20 Then
                sMth = ws1.Cells(row - 1, 2)
            Else
                sMth = ws1.Cells(row, 2)
            End If
            For i = 1 To num_holidays
                If sMth = my_holidays(i, 1) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = my_holidays(i, 2) Then
                    ws1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                End If
            Next i
        Next column
    Next row
```

---

*Update:*

> Question: If he had used Feb on row 10, I believe this would fail to mark 02 Mar.

```vb
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim column As Integer
    Dim sMth As String
    For row = 2 To last_row
        For column = 3 To 9
            sMth = ws1.Cells(row, 2)
            If ws1.Cells(row, 2) <> ws1.Cells(row - 1, 2) Then
                If ws1.Cells(row, column) > 21 Then sMth = ws1.Cells(row - 1, 2)
            ElseIf ws1.Cells(row, 2) <> ws1.Cells(row + 1, 2) Then
                If ws1.Cells(row, column) < 7 Then sMth = ws1.Cells(row + 1, 2)
            End If
            For i = 1 To num_holidays
                With ws1.Cells(row, column)
                    If sMth = my_holidays(i, 1) And .Value = my_holidays(i, 2) Then
                        .Interior.Color = vbCyan
                    End If
                End With
            Next i
        Next column
    Next row
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!
Can you modify the code such that if there is a holiday on February 27, it can also be highlighted? Currently it is not possible because in the row containing 27 of February, there is March in it.

Comment: Please check the updated code in my reply, it correctly mark 29 Mar and 27 Feb. Btw, 27 Feb is missed in your holiday table.

Comment: If he had used Feb on row 10, I believe this would fail to mark 02 Mar. Should add another condition to use row+1 in the first week.

Comment: I've updated the code to cover it.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, you can add a condition to check that the cell value is the minimum value until the end of the row. That indicates the day numbers do not reset in the same row, so the month has not changed.

```
    If ws1.Range("B" & row).Value = my_holidays(i, 1) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = my_holidays(i, 2) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(ws1.Cells(row, column), ws1.Cells(row, 9))) Then
        ws1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbCyan
    End If
```

But have you considered: what if 27 Feb was a holiday? You don't have any rows with both Feb and 27. If you change row 10 to March, then what if 27 Feb and 02 March were both holidays?

Have updated because your calendar is a little inconsistent as to which month you write in column B when the row is split between 2 months. This should cover all possibilities.

```
For row = 2 To last_row
    For column = 3 To 9
        For i = 1 To num_holidays
        
            If ws1.Cells(row, column).Value < 7 Then
                
                If ws1.Range("B" & row + 1).Value = my_holidays(i, 1) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = my_holidays(i, 2) Then
                    ws1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                End If
            
            ElseIf ws1.Cells(row, column).Value > 22 Then
                
                If ws1.Range("B" & row - 1).Value = my_holidays(i, 1) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = my_holidays(i, 2) Then
                    ws1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                End If
            
            Else
            
                If ws1.Range("B" & row).Value = my_holidays(i, 1) And ws1.Cells(row, column).Value = my_holidays(i, 2) Then
                    ws1.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color = vbCyan
                End If
            
            End If
                        
        Next i
                
    Next column
    
Next row
```

Comment: That's a good point. I see that your code fixed my question. But the question still remains how can I highlight February and 27.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple function in Excel to create a calendar that could replace the need of a VBA code I created.

The function is known as `SEQUENCE`.

```
=SEQUENCE(53, 7, "1/1/2024",1)
```

would create a calendar for 2024 entering 53 rows (weeks) and 7 columns (days of the week) starting from 1/1/2024 with a time step of 1 day.

I would convert the General format to Date format next.
[image]

For highlighting the holidays, I will use the conditional formatting as shown and apply to the entire cells with dates.
[image]